# Looking for a book on IPv6

Tags: ipv6

My standard for TCP/ip books is "TCP/IP Illustrated" by W. Richard Stevens. Can anyone recommend a book on IPv6 they think is that good?

Answer (score 2):

For Network Architects:
[http://www.amazon.com/IPv6-Network-Administration-David-Malone/dp/0596009348](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596009348)

For Programmers:
[http://www.amazon.com/IPv6-Essentials-Silvia-Hagen/dp/0596100582](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596100582)

For Server Admins:
[http://www.amazon.com/Understanding-IPv6-Second-Joseph-Davies/dp/0735624461](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735624461)

Comment: You better read the one * star comment before placing the order :-)

Comment: @Ring0, I think that review is fair for someone looking for a *Technical Guide* to IPv6 and *How-To* configure it on X platform. This book definitely concentrates on *why* IPv6 was invented, *the transition* from IPv4, and *specification over implementation*. If you just want to get IPv6 going in your network, this is not the book for you. If you want to know more, I would recommend this one. It's the difference between architects and construction workers; this one is for the former.

Comment: Ok, you own it seemingly.